# HTML button that's submitting an empty field even though it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, html, button

Here's the HTML button I'm working with:

```
<b>Other: </b><input type="number" id="AmntValue" data-target-element-id="SubmitAmnt" data-target-parameter="Amnt" onchange="setValueOnTarget(this);' +/* ' enableButton(SubmitAmnt);' */+ '"> 
<button class="button2" id="SubmitAmnt"  type="button" data-redirect-src="https://hub.deltasigmapi.org/donations/donations.aspx?appealid=1989&NumberOfPaymentsDisplay=0&GiftRecurrenceDisplay=0&GiftRecurrence=onetime&GiftAmount=" onclick="disableButton(this); addValueToQueryString(this); redirectPage(this);">Continue To Payment</button>
```

When someone hits the button but the "Other" text field is blank, it's supposed to **not** redirect and instead show an error message. Right now the error message displays, but only for a quick moment before it redirects anyway.

Here is my complete JavaScript code:

```
function setValueOnTarget(sourceElem) {
    var targetId = sourceElem.getAttribute('data-target-element-id');
    if (targetId) {
        var targetElem = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (targetElem) {
            var valueToSet;
            var parameterToSet;
            if (sourceElem.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'SELECT') {
                valueToSet = sourceElem.options[sourceElem.selectedIndex].value;
            }
            if (sourceElem.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT') {
                if (sourceElem.type.toUpperCase() == 'NUMBER' || sourceElem.type.toUpperCase() == 'TEXT') {
                    valueToSet = sourceElem.value;
                }
            }
            targetElem.setAttribute('data-value-set-by-other-element', valueToSet);
            parameterToSet = sourceElem.getAttribute('data-target-parameter');
            targetElem.setAttribute('data-target-parameter', parameterToSet);
            EnableButton(targetElem)
        }
    }
}

function disableButton(btn) {
    btn.disabled = true;
}

function EnableButton(btn) {
    btn.disabled = false;
}

function addValueToQueryString(elem) {
    var src = elem.getAttribute('data-redirect-src');
    var newValue = elem.getAttribute('data-value-set-by-other-element');
    var parameter = elem.getAttribute('data-target-parameter');
    if (newValue && parameter) {
        if (src && newValue && parameter) {
            var newSrc;
            newSrc = src + newValue;
            elem.setAttribute('data-redirect-src', newSrc);
        } else {
            displayError('Could not find the URL to redirect to');
        }
    } else {
        displayError('No value or parameter has been set. Please set a proper value.');
    }
}

function redirectPage(elem) {
    var src = elem.getAttribute('data-redirect-src');
    window.location = src;
}

function displayError(message) {
    var userMessage = document.getElementById('userMessage');
    userMessage.innerHTML = message;
    userMessage.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    userMessage.style.color = 'white';
    userMessage.style.display = 'block';
}

function displaySuccess(message) {
    var userMessage = document.getElementById('userMessage1');
    userMessage.innerHTML = message;
    userMessage.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    userMessage.style.color = 'white';
    userMessage.style.display = 'block';
}
```

I'm not sure if something's wrong with the code I put in the button or in the JavaScript.

Comment: You need to remove redirectPage(this); from the onclick and add it to addValueToQueryString(elem) function based on success. So if no error is thrown from addValueToQueryString() you then fire redirectPage()

Comment: Another reason why code in markup should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Disable button by default

The `button` should be disabled by default, and should only be enabled when the expected `input` value is detected. It appears you already have a mechanism for this in your example, but you have some impediments to overcome first:

1. `button` should be `disabled` by default. Do this in the HTML:
   `<button disabled …>Continue To Payment</button>`
2. `input`'s `onchange` handler should just call `setValueOnTarget()`, because this function already calls `EnableButton()`. In the HTML:
   `<input onchange="setValueOnTarget(this);" … >`
3. Remove the call to `redirectPage()` from the `button`'s `onclick` handler and move it into `addValueToQueryString()` after you have assigned a value to `newSrc`.
4. Add a call to `EnableButton()` after you call `displayError()` in cases where you want to allow the user to modify the `input` and try again.

**For example:**

```js
function setValueOnTarget(sourceElem) {
    var targetId = sourceElem.getAttribute('data-target-element-id');
    if (targetId) {
        var targetElem = document.getElementById(targetId);
      console.log(targetElem);
        if (targetElem) {
            var valueToSet;
            var parameterToSet;
            if (sourceElem.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'SELECT') {
                valueToSet = sourceElem.options[sourceElem.selectedIndex].value;
            }
            if (sourceElem.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT') {
                if (sourceElem.type.toUpperCase() == 'NUMBER' || sourceElem.type.toUpperCase() == 'TEXT') {
                    valueToSet = sourceElem.value;
                }
            }
            targetElem.setAttribute('data-value-set-by-other-element', valueToSet);
            parameterToSet = sourceElem.getAttribute('data-target-parameter');
            targetElem.setAttribute('data-target-parameter', parameterToSet);
            EnableButton(targetElem);
        }
    }
}

function disableButton(btn) {
    btn.disabled = true;
}

function EnableButton(btn) {
    btn.disabled = false;
}

function addValueToQueryString(elem) {
    var src = elem.getAttribute('data-redirect-src');
    var newValue = elem.getAttribute('data-value-set-by-other-element');
    var parameter = elem.getAttribute('data-target-parameter');
    if (newValue && parameter) {
        if (src && newValue && parameter) {
            var newSrc;
            newSrc = src + newValue;
            elem.setAttribute('data-redirect-src', newSrc);
            redirectPage(elem);
        } else {
            displayError('Could not find the URL to redirect to');
        }
    } else {
        displayError('No value or parameter has been set. Please set a proper value.');
        EnableButton(elem);
    }
}

function redirectPage(elem) {
    var src = elem.getAttribute('data-redirect-src');
    window.location = src;
}

function displayError(message) {
    var userMessage = document.getElementById('userMessage');
    userMessage.innerHTML = message;
    userMessage.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    userMessage.style.color = 'white';
    userMessage.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<b>Other: </b>
<input
       type="number"
       id="AmntValue"
       data-target-element-id="SubmitAmnt"
       data-target-parameter="Amnt"
       onchange="setValueOnTarget(this);"> 
<button
        disabled
        class="button2" 
        id="SubmitAmnt"
        type="button"
        data-redirect-src="https://hub.deltasigmapi.org/donations/donations.aspx?appealid=1989&NumberOfPaymentsDisplay=0&GiftRecurrenceDisplay=0&GiftRecurrence=onetime&GiftAmount="
        onclick="disableButton(this); addValueToQueryString(this);">Continue To Payment</button>

<div id="userMessage"></div>
```

Comment: I just want to counter that there are situations where this has been a usability concern in the product I work on. In very large forms where the required fields are not immediately clear, people aren't sure where to go when they see "Submit" is disabled. Enabling it and performing validation on submit means that the page displays a change (and hopefully scrolls up) to whatever was missed.

Comment: Sure, and I might have given a different answer if this were a very large form. In isolation, we have a single input and single button. It is apparent that you cannot submit until you make some kind of input. In this case, simply entering a number is enough to enable the button. There several other things I would change about this script as well, but I was trying to honor the OP's original intent as much as possible. And the code already contained this functionality, but it was improperly implemented.

Comment: gfullam, Thank you very much! I knew that I had the basis of what I wanted; I hadn't realized that I was just placing the code incorrectly, if you will. I appreciate the assistance, everything works great and as it should now!  As for the usability concern, I agree there would need to be more on a larger form, but this script is for the single input field that you see here.  So again, I appreciate the help.